# Is it possible to "snap to pixel" after a CSS translate?

Tags: css, transform

I created a modal box and vertically centred it using a [technique Chris Coyer mentioned](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/). The only problem I've found with it so far is that sometimes the box is offset by half a pixel, which can make some of the children look a little wonky. My question is,: is it possible to snap the result to the nearest whole pixel?

**Update**

Here are a couple of pictures to better illustrate the issue. In this first image, you can see the text inputs and link underlines have rendered correctly:

[image: Modal box with crisp lines]

The second image shows the effect after the CSS transforms have been used. Notice the blur of the link underline and the incorrectly rendered text inputs.

[image]

Although the second image doesn't show it, occasionally I notice the top and bottom white lines wit the same blurred effect.

For the record, the text inputs are styled using simple borders and a background colour. I've included the CSS for those inputs here so you can see there's nothing special happening:

```
input {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -1px #D5D5D5 inset;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: border-color 0.1s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "the children look a little wonky"? Are you talking about antialiasing problems? Can you show us a screenshot or reproduce the problem in jsFiddle?

Comment: @brianpeiris I've added pictures to better explain the question

Comment: Honestly, the differences are barely perceptible to me. I used an image comparison tool and there are actually more differences in the compression artifacts than actual differences (because you saved the screenshots as JPEGs). It would be easier to answer your question if you reproduced it in jsFiddle.

Comment: Y'know, the more I look at this problem, the more I agree with you, @brianpeiris. It's too small an issue to really worry about.

Comment: It depends on your problem. I've got this issue and because of the borders of the objects within and the surrounding colours its really noticeable as it creates a 'tear' between elements.

Comment: A year later—I still think this is a big issue, especially when dealing with many images on a page that have a translateY(-50%) or translateX, in my case—the browser spits out a matrix with a half pixel (-56.5). Would be nice to figure out a way to tell all browsers to only render translate's to whole pixels

Comment: This is still a problem I run into today. Although the OP discusses the issue surrounding transforms, you can run into this issue when the height of your container is a sub pixel value - most often than not we use pt, em, or rem to define font-sizes, which result in sub pixels, which can affect the rendering of multiple containers. What you end up with are faint lines most noticeable when you are using backgrounds in said containers. Haven't found a solution. Going back to px sizing is a regression.

Answer (score 7):

The only bulletproof solution is to ensure that your element occupies an *even* number of pixels. If the height (or width) is not divisible by 2, then it will attempt to render your element on a half-pixel, causing the blurriness.

Firefox doesn't have this issue because it supports true subpixel rendering. So, even though your element is on a half-pixel, Firefox handles it elegantly.

In my experience, Webkit typically snaps elements to the nearest pixel –– (for instance, when using the `letter-spacing` property) -- so it's kinda strange that it doesn't behave the same way for `translate`.

Answer (score 3):

In some browsers you can avoid 3d transforms and use 2d transforms instead, the translation will snap to pixels by default:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[image: rendering is snapped to pixels]

```
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
```

[image: rendering is anti-aliased]

**JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/epijal/3/edit

Comment: I am using 2D transforms but I still get the effect. Curiously, checking the link on this page in my version of Firefox (23) shows both demonstrations with crisp lines

Comment: I also only see the antialiasing problem in Chrome. Firefox seems to have a different rendering algorithm that accounts for cases like this (I think).

Comment: @JamesLong If you're using -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; or something else is triggering the element to be in its own layer, Chrome will still have this issue.

Comment: 2D transforms will cause subpixel anti-aliasing with an odd number of pixels pulled left at -50%.

Comment: The second one is still blurry on Chrome (61.0.3163.100)

Comment: I added a caveat to this answer to reflect the inconsistency across browsers

Comment: use `display: table` together with non-3d `translate` seems to give best results in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

As I encountered same problem with subpixels in Chrome and in version 64 it still can't handle subpixel transform values , I decided to write small js script, that fixes subpixel problem. 
You can find it on [github](https://github.com/engray/subpixelFix). It simply rounds transform value to full pixel.

[image: how subpixel works]

Hope someone will find it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I always use `perspective: 1px;`, for example:

```
{
  margin: 50% 0 0 50%;
  perspective: 1px;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```